# How to display all SDK versions of iphone/ipad in simulator selection list?

Tags: deployment, sdk, xcode4, ios-simulator

I'm unable to choose the lower than 4 version of SDK simulator in the simulator selection list in xcode4. There are iOS SDK 4+ (for iPhone) and iOS SDK 3.2 (for iPad) simulator versions only. I have set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 3.1 but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we need to download and install previous version of Xcode and SDK. All the versions could be found on Apple's developer site. Also, there is one simple instruction that can be found here:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/download-and-install-older-versions-of-xcode-xcode-previous-releases.html

Answer (score 0):

In the project editor choose your build target and then choose the summary pane.  In the summary pane there is a drop down box where you can choose the deployment target.  This may or may not help because it sounds like you're already changing the variable directly in the build settings.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the value in the build settings. Also, I have changed the value in summary tab but still nothing changes and simulator list is the same :(. Did I something wrong changing the value in the build settings?

Comment: I don't think it matters where you change it.  Very weird, I answered the question based on previous experience and previous projects but now I can't change it on my current project to anything below 4.3.  I just upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.1.  The drop menu will change to lower but I can't get it to run as older versions.  Need to investigate further.  Also you can change it both project wise and target wise but neither is working.

Comment: I have posted it on apple developer forums. Hope to get an answer :)